# React issue mapping payload to table with children array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting a payload and trying to map the data to a table.  I am having difficulty with mapping because of the auditline array. 
    Does anyone know of way of flattening the auditline so that I can map my data correctly.

```
payload:
    action: 
     id: 301
     module : 2
     name: "Create folder"
     auditline:
     0: Id: 1723
        description:"Folder has been changed from Matlab to C#"
     1: Id: 1724
        description:"Folder name is Matlab"
```

This is the map function snippet.

```
       <TableBody>
          {data.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map(n => {
            const isSelected = this.isSelected(n.id);
            return (
              <TableRow
                hover
                onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n.id)}
                role="checkbox"
                aria-checked={isSelected}
                tabIndex={-1}
                key={n.id}
                selected={isSelected}
              >
                  <TableCell>{n.action.name}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{n.auditLines.description}</TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            );
          })}
```

Comment: Do you want every audit description to be rendered or only the first one ?

Comment: Hi. I would every audit description to be rendered and there can be an unlimited autlines

Comment: Alright, should they be joined together in a single string or put in different cells for each one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `map` your array of audits to create multiple table cells :

```
<TableRow
    hover
    onClick={event => this.handleClick(event, n.id)}
    role="checkbox"
    aria-checked={isSelected}
    tabIndex={-1}
    key={n.id}
    selected={isSelected}
    >
        <TableCell>{n.action.name}</TableCell>
        {n.auditLines.map(audit => <TableCell key={audit.id}>{audit.description}</TableCell>)}
    <TableCell>
    </TableCell>
</TableRow>
```

Or, if you want all of them in a single one, use [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)